# Custom Splash Screen on Login RHEL

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, rhel

I was wondering if it was possible to display a splash screen when you log into an account in a RHEL server? not via /etc/motd as that is global but to an specific user.

Ideally I would like to show uptime and services running when a service account is logged in.

Kind regards,

R,

Answer (score 0):

Check manual page for `sshd_config`. There is `Banner` option and you can customize it per-user.

Also `motd` can be dynamic. Check this answer on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/459229/is-it-possible-to-put-commands-in-etc-motd):

> However, it's possible to execute a shell script at login time that will have the same result. This is usually achieved by adapting the `/etc/profile` script that is executed each time a user logs in. A useful practice is to put the command you want to be executed in a script named `/etc/motd.sh` and call this script from `/etc/profile`, usually at about the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the target user's .Bash_profile and put inside of it the commands to show stuffs like cpuinfo meminfo...
Here's an example.

```
let upSeconds="$(/usr/bin/cut -d. -f1 /proc/uptime)" 
let secs=$((${upSeconds}%60))

let mins=$((${upSeconds}/60%60))
let hours=$((${upSeconds}/3600%24))
let days=$((${upSeconds}/86400))
UPTIME=`printf "%d days, %02dh%02dm%02ds" "$days" "$hours" "$mins" "$secs"`

echo "`date +"%A, %e %B %Y, %r"`
`uname -srmo`
Uptime.............: ${UPTIME}
Memory.............: `cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree | awk {'print $2'}`kB (Free) / `cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk {'print $2'}`kB (Total)
Load Averages......: ${one}, ${five}, ${fifteen} (1, 5, 15 min)
Running Processes..: `ps ax | wc -l | tr -d " "`
IP Addresses.......: `/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | /bin/grep "inet addr" | /usr/bin/cut -d ":" -f 2 | /usr/bin/cut -d " " -f 1`"
```

this example will show you something like this:

Friday, 15 April 2016, 04:47:41 PM

Linux 2.6.18-128.el5 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Uptime.............: 2 days, 02h05m06s

Memory.............: 1805240kB (Free) / 4037732kB (Total)

Load Averages......: 0.77, 0.74, 0.89 (1, 5, 15 min)

Running Processes..: 230

IP Addresses.......: X.X.X.X

ENJOY!